# Como formatar código Json em HTML?

Tags: json, wordpress

Boa tarde galera.
Preciso de uma ajuda. Estou utilizando a API: JSON API do Wordpress e nele libera o .content que retorna o codigo HTML, do post. Como pegar esse json que contém código HTML e retorna-lo como código HTML?

Ex conteúdo do json content:

```
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Estréia do Blog</h2> 
<p style="text-align: justify;">
    Olá galera, tudo bem? É com muito prazer que estreio o meu blog pessoal, onde pretendo compartilhar meus conhecimentos, notícias atuais, minhas opiniões sobre assuntos da tecnologia. Falar sobre programação, desenvolvimento, projetos e qualquer coisa sobre a área.
</p> 
<p style="text-align: justify;">
    Meu nome é Pedro Franco, sou atualmente desenvolvedor de sites em WordPress em uma agência de publicidade em Belo Horizonte &#8211; MG chamada M.Bottaro. Desenvolvendo sites desenfreadamente ( comumente de agências &#8216;rsrs&#8217; ), e procuro sempre buscar aprimorar com metodologias ágeis e padrões me agilizar cada vez mais e me manter dentro da tendência do desenvolvimento WEB. São muitos detalhes e tenho de estar sempre estudando e aprendendo cada vez mais. Porém, realizei projetos em outras linguagens, em outras tecnologias. Por exemplo, no curso técnico desenvolvia em Java Web, e meu TCC que se encontra no GitHub <strong><a href="https://github.com/pedr0369/ProjetoPizzariaEureka">Pizzaria Eureka</a> </strong>foi desenvolvido nesta tecnologia, falarei em posts futuros sobre esta experiência. Em um estágio que realizei no <a href="http://www.crea-mg.org.br">CREA-MG</a> desenvolvia em C# e diversos frameworks com toda uma metodologia fixa por trás, uma experiência que me agregou muito tanto profissionalmente quanto pessoalmente e também falarei desta experiência em postagens futuras.
</p> 
<h3 style="text-align: center;">OBJETIVO DO BLOG</h3> 
<p style="text-align: justify;">
    Meu pretexto com este BLOG, é de que além de mostrar meu portfólio, pretendo também, informalmente escrever artigos periodicamente sobre o contexto do qual descrevi acima. Farei o possível para manter o blog sempre atualizado e com postagens frequentes, e as postagens curtas e diretas, sem muita delonga.
</p> 
<p style="text-align: justify;">
    &#8216;Nessa área de tecnologia, guardar conhecimento apenas para si mesmo não é algo legal, e acaba atrasando apenas a si mesmo, tanto que aqueles que compartilham seus conhecimentos e ajudam dentro do possível a comunidade relacionada a sua área acabam agregando aos outros e a si próprio.&#8217;
</p> 
<p style="text-align: justify;">
    Portanto, sempre que possível encontro um tempo, para tentar dentro de minha realidade aprender sempre mais e ajudar com o pouco que sei a quem precisa.
</p> 
<p style="text-align: justify;">
    No mais, sejam bem vindos. E espero que posso agregar conhecimento a todos leitores.
</p>
```

Comment: Você quer pegar esse conteúdo retornado e jogar numa div?

Comment: Eu quero que não leia como uma string e sim que o browser execute o código descrito pelo json.

Comment: Então, você quer renderizar o conteúdo na página.

Comment: Não uma página, e sim um conteúdo de uma json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supondo que você está recebendo os dados no front-end via javascript você pode inserir assim:

```js
var jsonString = '<h2 style="text-align: center;">Estréia do Blog</h2> <p style="text-align: justify;">Olá galera, tudo bem? É com muito prazer que estreio o meu blog pessoal, onde pretendo compartilhar meus conhecimentos, notícias atuais, minhas opiniões sobre assuntos da tecnologia. Falar sobre programação, desenvolvimento, projetos e qualquer coisa sobre a área.</p> <p style="text-align: justify;">Meu nome é Pedro Franco, sou atualmente desenvolvedor de sites em WordPress em uma agência de publicidade em Belo Horizonte &#8211; MG chamada M.Bottaro. Desenvolvendo sites desenfreadamente ( comumente de agências &#8216;rsrs&#8217; ), e procuro sempre buscar aprimorar com metodologias ágeis e padrões me agilizar cada vez mais e me manter dentro da tendência do desenvolvimento WEB. São muitos detalhes e tenho de estar sempre estudando e aprendendo cada vez mais. Porém, realizei projetos em outras linguagens, em outras tecnologias. Por exemplo, no curso técnico desenvolvia em Java Web, e meu TCC que se encontra no GitHub <strong><a href="https://github.com/pedr0369/ProjetoPizzariaEureka">Pizzaria Eureka</a> </strong>foi desenvolvido nesta tecnologia, falarei em posts futuros sobre esta experiência. Em um estágio que realizei no <a href="http://www.crea-mg.org.br">CREA-MG</a> desenvolvia em C# e diversos frameworks com toda uma metodologia fixa por trás, uma experiência que me agregou muito tanto profissionalmente quanto pessoalmente e também falarei desta experiência em postagens futuras.</p> <h3 style="text-align: center;">OBJETIVO DO BLOG</h3> <p style="text-align: justify;">Meu pretexto com este BLOG, é de que além de mostrar meu portfólio, pretendo também, informalmente escrever artigos periodicamente sobre o contexto do qual descrevi acima. Farei o possível para manter o blog sempre atualizado e com postagens frequentes, e as postagens curtas e diretas, sem muita delonga.</p> <p style="text-align: justify;">&#8216;Nessa área de tecnologia, guardar conhecimento apenas para si mesmo não é algo legal, e acaba atrasando apenas a si mesmo, tanto que aqueles que compartilham seus conhecimentos e ajudam dentro do possível a comunidade relacionada a sua área acabam agregando aos outros e a si próprio.&#8217;</p> <p style="text-align: justify;">Portanto, sempre que possível encontro um tempo, para tentar dentro de minha realidade aprender sempre mais e ajudar com o pouco que sei a quem precisa.</p> <p style="text-align: justify;">No mais, sejam bem vindos. E espero que posso agregar conhecimento a todos leitores.</p>';
            
var texto = document.getElementById('texto');
texto.innerHTML = jsonString;
```

```html
<div id="texto"></div>
```

Note que estou me baseando na string que você postou, que **não é um JSON válido**, então você pode ter resultados variados com esse método. Se tiver algum erro edite a pergunta que tentamos adequar.

Comment: Cara, só tenho a agradecer, quebrei a cabeça pensando em mil coisas até mais complexas talvez, e a resposta era simplesmente isso. Obrigado.